# Autocomplete textview not showing results under certain situations in android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I have an autocomplete textview in my android activity, in which the results are obtained by passing a string arraylist in the arrayadapter. The string arraylist contains elements in this format:

```
city-name-country(code)
```

for example the one entry in the string arraylist is like this:

```
Cochin-Kochi International Airport-India(COK)
```

When I start entering characters, it starts showing me results from the string arraylist based on the `city` but If I need to get results based on the `code` ie `cok` what changes should I make in the code? I mean, a user should get results even when he types city or code. In my case when I type `cok` In my case there is no results showing in the autocomplete textview. But actually there is one entry corresponding to the characters cok ie Kochi International Airport. But I'm not able to get this result. Can some one please help me...  This is the code of my autocomplete textview:

```
actv1=(AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
loc=SplashScreen.loc;//obtained from a static arraylist in another activity.
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,loc);
actv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

EDIT:

I have added the following code to my program, and the problem is that when I type `COK` the result `Cochin-Kochi International Airport-India(COK)` just flashes for less than 1 second as suggestion in the autocomplete textview, and after that it vanishes. The suggestion is shown for only less than 1 second and displays nothing in the autocomplete textview. What is the possible error in the code which I have implemented?

```
actv1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                 String filter = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String listItem : loc) {
                    if (listItem.toLowerCase().contains(filter))
                    {
                        listItems.add(listItem);

                    }

                }
                if (listItems.size() < 1){

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "No entries contain your search parameters",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                toast.show();

                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
                actv1.setAdapter(adapt);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: You will have to create a custom ArrayAdapter, and override the `getFilter()` `performFiltering()` methods. Here is an example : https://gist.github.com/tobiasschuerg/3554252

Comment: Can you please help me by giving the code, cause I'm new to this...

Comment: You do not have to use `addTextChangedListener`, use the filtering method it explain earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simon mentioned, you'll need to customize the filter for the `ArrayAdapter` in order to change how the filtering logic works.  Unfortunately this is not an easy task for someone new to adapters.  Also, even though you can override the filter and update the logic, you shouldn't.  It can lead to many other problems.  I suggest using the `ArrayBaseAdapter` from this [opensource repo](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters).  Its just like using the `ArrayAdapter` but provides a simple method to implement which allows you to specify how the filtering logic behaves.

Comment: Can you please help me in implementing custom array adapter with filtering, cause I'm new to this field..

Comment: You don't create a new Adapter like that for every text change.  Keep the list and adapter as is and call `adapter#getFilter().filter(constraint)`.  If you want to customize the search logic, check out the link I provided in my answer